# IE и нестандартные шрифты

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

НУ в общем задача стояла натянуть готовую вёрстку на джумлу, верстальщик бестолковый оказался, и кучу всякой не кроссобраузерной фигни напихал, в том числе и шрифт, самое главное без этого шрифта весь стиль сайт теряется, не красиво смотрится( А IE при загрузке сайта просит загрузить шрифт, можно ли от этого как-то избавиться? Если кто-то сталкивался, подскажите, пож-та...
Вот как прописан шрифт:

```
  @font-face {
    font-family:'PFDR';
    src:url('pfdintextcondpro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src:url('pfdintextcondpro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pfdintextcondpro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pfdintextcondpro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pfdintextcondpro-regular-webfont.svg#PFDR') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    }
```

Comment: Точно не подскажу как, но есть способ указывать адрес шрифта и тянуть его с сервера на клиент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@font-face. Нестандартный шрифт средствами CSS.](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/font-face-non-standart-fonts-on-css.html)

Comment: Да вроде у меня всё также, как в статье расширение eot да и прописано также

Comment: Лучше убей Ишака))) в этом вся и беда что 20% юзеров инета не знают что есть другие браузеры, из них 2% еще мусолят IE6) Статистика Google Analytics за последние 30 дней)

Comment: Да он уже испарился) Я так думаю, что это настройка в браузере клиента, какой-нибудь безопасный режим, т.к. я проверил и в 7 и в 8 всё нормально)

Comment: @mctrane если 2% посетителей написать что - "иди и скачай нормальный браузер" ты сделаешь этот мир добрее)))

Comment: Надо просто в ВК запретить вообще IE)) Тогда все качнут нормальные браузера, но ИЕ чем выше версия, тем лучше, т.е. исправляется по-тихоньку, но его "быстродействие" поражает, он прежде чем грузить страницу ещё что-то думает) И это при том, что без всяких яндекс баров

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так. По-моему, такое поддерживается только современными браузерами (ну и IE естественно):

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'myrad';
        src: url(fonts/MYRIAD.OTF);/*путь к нестандартному шрифту*/
    }

    .myriadPro {
        font-family: 'myrad' !important;
    }
```

Comment: Ну вроде у меня также, посмотрите, я добавил в свой пост код.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в вопросе приведен самый кроссбраузерное решение. Оно отрабатывает с IE 6. Может вы неправильно пользуетесь или отсутствуют файлы, приведенные в урлах

Comment: Я не говорил, что не работает, я говорю о том что браузер просит скачать шрифт. Но я наверно понял из-за чего, настройка в браузере какая-то

Comment: Короче говоря это проделки MS для того чтобы убить IE6. У меня к примеру изображения вверх ногами и задом-наперед! Так что сколько бы Portable версий ты не использовал, результат будет тот же!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, да, в моём случаи была проблема с индивидуальным компьютером, потому что только у клиента такое окошечко выскакивает) Проверили и у его знакомых и у своих)